# What are established Twitter Libraries for iOS (iPhone & iPad)?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I used to use [MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) as my main twitter library for iOS, however, the last commit to the project's master branch is more than one year old (at the time of this writing) and the documentation is not that great. Now I am starting a new project and would like to get rid of the "clunky" MGTwitterEngine, what are other twitter libraries out there for iOS? Which are your favorites and why?

I found the following so far:

- [MPOAuth](https://github.com/thekarladam/MPOAuth)
- [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/) (provides a lot more than just Twitter sharing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple announced in the WWDC keynote that Twitter access will be built into the OS in iOS 5, so assuming that means built-in API access its likely that all third-party Twitter libraries are being left to wither. Those who develop for iOS have access to the beta APIs, so even though we can't say anything for sure about future API releases, they could (NDA notwithstanding).

That being said, I'd add [DDSocialClient](https://github.com/ddeville/DDSocialClient) to the list. Like ShareKit it does a whole lot more than Twitter, but it's much less prescriptive on user interface. It restricts itself mostly to the nuts and bolts of the service integration. Whether you think that's liberating or just more work is probably a judgment call.

Comment: Thanks, iOS integration is clearly the way to go forward and will take a look at DDSocialClient

Answer (score 0):

iOS5 is coming out soon but i'm using MGTwitterEngine and it works like a charm. http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa

Also you can try sharekit but I dont like it as much.

Comment: I believe so. Check this out much better:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/TwitterFrameworkReference.pdf

Comment: The doc says, `Availability - Available in iOS 5.0 and later.`

Comment: yup you can use MGTwitterEngine if you want to support 4.0 as well. I used it and it worked pretty well.

Comment: Did you try implementing it for iOS 5 because I don't think it works for it.

Comment: I haven't tried it for iOS5 sorry. You can just use the Apple library for iOS5 > if MGTwitterEngine doesn't work for it.

Comment: yeah, this is what i am doing at the moment. I will have to use MGTwitterEngine  for iOS4 and Twitter.Lib for iOS 5 :( .